# Architecture x86_64 missing while creating XCFrameworks

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, xcframework

I am trying to create `XCFramework` using `XCode 12.2`.

Using following command to generate Simulator archives:

```
xcodebuild archive -scheme MyFramework -archivePath ~/Documents/frameworks/MyFramework_iphonesimulator.xcarchive -destination "generic/platform=iOS Simulator" -sdk iphonesimulator SKIP_INSTALL=NO
```

For iOS:

```
xcodebuild archive -scheme MyFramework -archivePath ~/Documents/frameworks/MyFramework_iphoneos.xcarchive -sdk iphoneos -destination "generic/platform=iOS"  SKIP_INSTALL=NO
```

Then

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework -framework "~/frameworks/MyFramework_iphoneos.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework" -framework "~/frameworks/MyFramework_iphonesimulator.xcarchive/Products/Library/Frameworks/MyFramework.framework" -output ~/Documents/frameworks/xcframeworks/MyFramework.xcframework
```

When I try to integrate and use in other project am getting error as

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
> "*OBJC_CLASS*$_SnapshotHandler", referenced from:
> objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o

`SnapshotHandler` is a class from MyFramework.

I checked valid architectures it set to `Standard Architectures`, also Build active  architectures only set to `NO`

If I build Framework with `XCode 11.6` then call valid architectures with be added (i386 & x86_64).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe setting `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION` to `YES` will help?

Comment: Already tried. not working

Comment: Are both framework and project written in ObjectiveC?

Comment: framework is in ObjC & Project in Swift.

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @meowmeowmeow Yes. In User-Defined configurations VALID_ARCHS where configured and that been used which has x86_64 missing. After fixing/removing that configuration it worked.